# (2nd term C++)(Homework)Linked Lists Advice

Tags: c++, singly-linked-list

I am currently writing a program in C++ that uses linked lists. The problem is, I can't really seem to figure out how to use linked lists. I know (A little) how to use classes though.

This is the LinkedList.h file given by the teacher (So I can't modify anything)

**LinkedList.h**

```
struct Node
{
    void* data_;
    Node* next_;

    Node()
    {
        data_ = 0;
        next_ = 0;
    }
};

class LinkedList
{
private:
    Node* first_;
    Node* last_;
    long listLen_;

public:
    LinkedList();
    ~LinkedList();
    void AddLinkToBack(void* ptr);
    void* RemoveLinkFromFront();
    Node* GetFirstNode();
    long GetListLength();
};
```

I really just need advice on what to do for the Linked List function definitions but I will also listen to advice on improving my code. Thank you :)

Edit: Removed the other code in case someone in a future class stumbles upon this post.

Comment: What do you mean advice on what to do for Linked List function definitions? Do you want to know how to implement them? Or what?

Comment: Yeah, I can't really figure out how to implement them at all. I was sick last week when they went over it in class =/

Comment: `void*`? There is a special kind of bad code that only academics write.

Comment: From the text: "A void pointer is used so that this class does not have to know about the Shell class."

Comment: @Beta The default copy constructor and assignment operator makes real problem here. Also the first capital letter in methods looks retarded like C♯.

Comment: Then the text is obsolete. Templates are a much safer tool for that purpose.

Comment: Which was also mentioned in the text. However, the assignment stated that we weren't supposed to use templates so that we could do it in a way that wasn't discussed in detail in the book.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to describe how to implement each function. Not going to give you the code.

`LinkedList()`: This is your constructor for the linked list. This function should be a part of the class where you have defined a linked list. It will be called whenever a linked list is initialised. You can use it define the first node of a linked list and set it to NULL.

`~LinkedList()`: This is your destructor for the linked list. It will deallocate all the memory allocated to the linked list. Implement it such that it deallocates memory for all elements of the linked list as opposed to just setting the first element to NULL.

`AddLinkToBack(void* ptr)`: Add an element to the end of the linked list. This should traverse to the end of the linked list and set the next pointer of the last element to the pointer passed in the parameter. You should also dereference the void pointer before doing this.

`RemoveLinkFromFront()`: Remove the first element. To do this, you can set the first element of the list as first->next, and deallocate the memory given to the first element.

`GetFirstElement()`: Return a pointer to the first element of the linked list.

`GetListLength()`: Traverse the entire list and keep a pointer alongside which will increment every time you move to the next element. Return the counter when you reach the end of the linked list.

Comment: Keeping track of the list length with a counter that is initialized to zero in the constructor and incremented/decremented by the other functions would be a *much* more efficient way to implement `GetListLength`. Traversing the list just to count nodes isn't necessary.

Comment: You could then similarly keep track of a pointer to the last element to do the `AddLinkToBack` function in a more efficient manner.